# Terraform Throwing 'InvalidParameterValue' Address x.x.x.x does not fal within the subnet's address range.. it does

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Having an issue with a Terraform deployment. I have a module that creates a network, and then another module that creates a series of ec2 instances. These servers are required to have specific IP addresses, which are called out in the module (I would rather dynamically set these but for now they are 'hardcoded'). However, I am getting a warning that the IP address I am associating with the ec2 instance 'does not fall within the subnet's address range', but it is. Here is the basic breakdown:

```
servers
->main.tf
->variables.tf
->outputs.tf
network
->main.tf
->variables.tf
->outputs.tf
main.tf
```

The relevant bits are as follows:
network main.tf

```
# Create VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "foo" {
  cidr_block           = "192.168.1.0/24"
  enable_dns_hostnames = "true"
  enable_dns_support   = "true"

  tags = {
    Name = "foo"
  }
}

# Create a Subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet-1" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.foo.id
  cidr_block        = "192.168.1.0/24"
  availability_zone = "ca-central-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "subnet-1"
  }
}
```

servers main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "bar" {
  ami                         = var.some_ami
  instance_type               = "t3.medium"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  private_ip = "192.168.1.15"
  
  # root disk
  root_block_device {
    volume_size           = "60"
    volume_type           = "gp3"
    encrypted             = true
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "bar"
  }
}
```

main.tf

```
module "network" {
    source = "./network"
}

module "servers" {
    source = "./servers"
    subnet_id = module.network.aws_subnet
}
```

Everything works correctly, and I verified in AWS that the VPC is created, and the subnet is created, but for some reason when the server is getting created I get the following error:

> │ Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameterValue: Address 192.168.1.15 does not fall within the subnet's address range status code: 400

I left out some of the irrelevant bits of the tfs but everything else works as expected except this one thing. Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: What is in your outputs in the network module?

Comment: I see you passing `subnet_id` to `servers` module & using hardcoded `private_ip` in `servers` module. It won't work as both `servers` & `network` modules gets evaluated by Terraform graph API at the same time. If you would like to have a static ip to your `ec2` instance, put a `depends_on` on `network` module like `depends_on=[module.network]`  & give a try. This way, server module gets executed only after network module.

Answer (score 1):

Your `aws_instance` resource does not have `subnet_id` attribute. So instances are being launched in default subnet.

Add `subnet_id` attribute as below

```
resource "aws_instance" "bar" {
  ami                         = var.some_ami
  instance_type               = "t3.medium"
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  subnet_id = "your_subnet_id"
  private_ip = "192.168.1.15"
  
  # root disk
  root_block_device {
    volume_size           = "60"
    volume_type           = "gp3"
    encrypted             = true
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "bar"
  }
}
```

You could also use data resource to get the subnet id.

```
data "aws_subnet" "selected" {
  filter {
    name   = "tag:Name"
    values = ["myawesomesubnet"]
  }
}
```

Comment: The subnet ID is being passed in main.tf through:

```
module "servers" {
    source = "./servers"
    subnet_id = module.network.aws_subnet
}
```
is this not correct?

Comment: You are passing to the module. but the actual resource `aws_instance` needs `subnet_id` attribute to use it.